# read.table returns extra rows

Tags: r, dataframe, text-files

I am working with textfiles of many, long rows with varying number of elements. Each element in the rows are separated by \t and of course the rows are terminated by \n. I'm using read.table to read the textfiles. An example samplefile is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6utslbnwerwhi58/samplefile.txt

The sample file has 60 rows.

Code to read the file:

```
sampleData <- read.table("samplefile.txt", as.is=TRUE, fill = TRUE);
dim(sampleData);
```

The dim returns 70 rows when in fact it should be 60. When I try nrows=60 like

```
sampleData <- read.table("samplefile.txt", as.is=TRUE, fill = TRUE, nrows = 60);
dim(sampleData);
```

it does work, however, I don't know if doing so will delete some of the information. My suspicion is that the last portions of some of the rows are added to new rows. I don't know why that would be the case, however, as I have fill = TRUE;

I have also tried

> na.strings = "NA", fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, blank.lines.skip =
>   TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote = "", comment.char = ""

but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: `read.table` expects the number of elements in every row to be the same. You should use `scan` instead.

Comment: `readLines` is another helpful tool for this.

Comment: I haven't used scan or readLines before. It seems they just read item by item. How would I get it in a dataframe format with the different rows?

Comment: If you run `count.fields` on that file it appears that it only has 8 lines of data, and that the number of variables per row has a range of 22897-75294.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a reproducible example, try something like this:

```
# Make some fake data
R <- c("1 2 3 4","2 3 4","4 5 6 7 8")
writeLines(R, "samplefile.txt")

# read line by line
r <- readLines("samplefile.txt")

# split by sep
sp <- strsplit(r, " ")

# Make each into a list of dataframes (for rbind.fill)
sp <- lapply(sp, function(x)as.data.frame(t(x)))

# now bind
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(sp)
```

If this is similar to your actual problem, anyway.

Comment: It worked, but it takes a long time. So, I'm just getting it in the correct form and saving that as a txt file so I can read that in anytime after that without the long wait.
Thank you!